# Work details not calculating hours -- Planned Effort not calculating hours

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, sprint, capacity-planning

I am a project/product manager trying to plan a few releases for a product. Due to the small size of my team it’s important I utilize capacity planning, however ADO is not calculating the estimate/effort totals and I can only view capacities by looking at the Drop Plan tab.

This issue occurs in all of my projects even though I have assigned an original estimate (hours) and developer to each task.
Dragging/Dropping as advised [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops) does not resolve the issue

[image: Sprint Planning Panel]

[image: Work Details Panel]

I wish to achieve a work details panel resembling the following so I don't have to flip back/forth between the drop plan tab to view my team's capacity usage. [image: Screenshot],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have assigned an original estimate (hours) and developer to each task.

You have assigned the wrong field.

According to the icons in your screenshot, there are a user story and two tasks. In the tasks, you should assign the Remaining field.

[image: Remaining field]

After the Remaining field is filled, the Work details will show the correct data.

[image: Work details]

The Planned effort in Planning is the Story Points field of the user story.
[image: Story Points]
[image: Planning]

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the Capacity for each team member in the Capacity tab?
[image]

If not, this should solve your issue.